# Why would an lftp mirror operation slow down over time?

Tags: ftp, lftp

I have CCTV server that is backed up daily to a remote ftp server using an lftp command. The CCTV server saves videos to a new folder each day, the backup runs once a day at 1am, so each backup only affects 2 folders. After 28 days the local copies are all deleted.

The command I currently use is:

```
mirror --reverse --use-cache --allow-chown --allow-suid --no-umask --verbose
```

The file transfer rate when moving files has been consistent for 2 years, but the wait between folders is slowly increasing. This means that while the file transfer rate is 1Mb/s if you take the wall clock time that backing up 2GB takes each day, the average speed after 2 years is now down to 0.5Mb/s.

Is anything in my command causing the process to bloat? `--use-cache` for example?

Could I have the mirror command to run one thread per folder so that it can get on with loading folder contents while it's uploading other files?

Comment: How many directories already exist on the destination? If the directory containing those is very large due to a very large amount of subdirectories, then creating new subdirectories can become very slow.

Comment: The destination directory structure is /cctv/%year%/%month%/%day%/files.mp4 so each directory only contains a few subdirectories (up to 31) but the current year will have a total of around 300 subdirectories including recursion. And /cctv/ contains 600 in the same way. Is cumulative bad or just at each level?

Comment: Directory size matters per directory. Has there been rotation of these files, i.e. old versions have been removed? Depending on what filesystem is in use that can lead to filesystem fragmentation.

Comment: nope, but it's a shared server so other users may have done so. I'll ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying clearing the cache, and removing the `--use-cache` command entirely, my service provider admitted they were having "network issues" their end, which was causing `ls` commands to run very slowly.
Fortunately detailed logs  from my end were able to demonstrate their error, and now show things running at full speed.

Keep your logs people!!